# ICS File not showing RSVP button due

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I've been having an issue with the RSVP options showing up when I send out a calendar invite. It seems like it may be an issue with my RRULE by some reason.
When I use the following code for the ICS file it does not show the RSVP button

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Data::-//foo
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="Test";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@test.com
SEQUENCE:17
DTSTAMP:20180517T122445
DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20180518T000000
DTEND;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20180518T010000
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Test - May 18\, 2018
ORGANIZER;CN="Test":mailto:test@test.org
LOCATION:Mars
STATUS:CONFIRMED
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20180720T000000;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=FR;WKST=SU
UID:68588Atest@test.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the only reason but your RRULE is indeed incorrect. More specifically, the UNTIL value should be expressed in UTC time ( Z suffix).

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10 :

> If the "DTSTART" property is specified as a date with UTC
> time or a date with local time and time zone reference, then the
> UNTIL rule part MUST be specified as a date with UTC time.